# Map char array to char buffer

Tags: c

I have a binary file dumped into a char array.  Some part of the file can be associated with the `struct s1`.  Depending on a value in `struct1`, there will be `N` more bytes before another `struct struct2` can be assigned. I want to read these N bytes into another array and pass them off elsewhere, but I have not figured out how to do this.  Below is my attempt.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct s1{
    int x;
    int y;
    int N;
};

int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("myfile.xyz", "rb");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    int sz = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    // Populate buffer
    unsigned char buffer[sz];
    fread(buffer, sz, 1, fp);
    char *pos = (char*) buffer;  // current pos pointer to file buffer

    // map s1, starting at pos
    struct s1 *s1 = (struct s1*) pos;
    // extra code parsing of s1...
    pos += sizeof(struct s1);  // increment pointer to after struct

    int N = 10; // should be read from s1 (i.e. it is not(!) a static number)
    char *temp = (char*) malloc((N+1)*sizeof(char));
    // assign temp to be N bytes, starting at pos...
    // parse_temp(temp);
    pos += N;
    free(temp);
    return 0;
};
```

I have tried to make a for-loop as follows to populate `temp`:

```c
for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        *temp[i] = (char *) (pos+i); //both temp[i] and *temp[i]...
    };
```

but neither of the versions are compiling.  It also feels like this approach defeats the idea of just mapping the array in the same way as for the struct, since `temp` is a new memory block, not using the "pointer-to-raw-memory"-thinking I hope the struct-casting is doing.

I am slowly learning `c`, so this might be a trivial question with the right search terms...

Comment: I'm pretty sure this part: `struct s1 *s1 = (struct s1*) pos;` ... has undefined behavior due to alignment issues.

Comment: Yes you are right.  In my full code Im using `#pragma pack(1)`, forgot to add it in this MWE.  But thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: OK, so what exactly is your question?

Comment: I would like my char array `temp` to be populated by the `N` bytes starting right after `s1`, preferably by pointing to the same memory as `buffer`.  In the same way as the struct is just layed out in memory.  If that is not possible, I would be fine by copying each byte from `buffer[sizeof(s1):sizeof(s1)+N]` into a new array.

Comment: Arrays don't point. `temp` is not an array (it's a pointer). If you want to point `temp` at `buffer`, do `temp = buffer;` ... or `temp = pos;` or whichever position you want.

Comment: Ahh,  I see your point ( :) ), and it seems to work!  Thank you.

Comment: Oh, and your copy loop had a dereference on the wrong side: `temp[i] = *(pos+i);` (or just `temp[i] = pos[i]`, same thing). But that's just `memcpy()` anyway.

Comment: Oh, you are right. Damn pointers!